# View Won't Accept First Responder Status

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm creating a new window and view programmatically. I need the view to accept First Responder status. For whatever reason it's not.

I'm doing this old school because I want my app to be compatible with older versions of OSX. Here's what I've got:

```
- (IBAction)startShow:(id)sender {

    // Capture the main display
    if (CGDisplayCapture( kCGDirectMainDisplay ) != kCGErrorSuccess) {
        NSLog( @"Couldn't capture the main display!" );
    }

    // Get the shielding window level
    windowLevel = CGShieldingWindowLevel();

    // Get the screen rect of our main display
    screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

    // Put up a new window
    displayWindow = [[ShowWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect
                                             styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                               backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                 defer:NO screen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];
    [displayWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];

    [displayWindow setLevel:windowLevel];
    [displayWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

    // Load show window with options from settings window. 
    [displayWindow loadOptions:screenRect];

}
```

Just to clarify, displayWindow is an instance of ShowWindow, which is a subclass of NSWindow. In my ShowWindow class I'm doing the following:

```
  - (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
  {
      return YES;
  }    

  - (void) loadOptions:(NSRect)screenRect {


    // Create custom view to hold text fields
    view = [[ShowView alloc] initWithFrame: screenRect];   
    [self setContentView:view];

    // Track Title Text Field Initialize
    textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, screenRect.size.height / 4, screenRect.size.width, 350)];
    [textField setStringValue:@"My Label"];
    [textField setBezeled:NO];
    [textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textField setEditable:NO];
    [textField setSelectable:NO];
    [textField setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [textField setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:92]];
    [textField setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];

    // Add track title text field to main view. 
    [view addSubview:textField];

    // Make the view first responder
    [self makeFirstResponder:view];

}
```

view is an instance of ShowView, which is a subclass of NSView. Last but not least here's what I've got going on in ShowView:

```
// Next four methods set main view as first responder to accept keyboard input
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    NSLog(@"I accepted being a first responder! Yea!");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    return YES;
}

- (void)insertText:(NSString *)input
{ 

}
```

Comment: ...Aaaand I figured it out. I can't answer and accept since I'm too new of a user.

Basically I called another method after making my new window the key window. Once I made "loadOptions" happen before "makeKeyAndOrderFront" it accepted first responder status.